# How to build persistent element like facebook chatbar which not reload when navigate to any page?

Tags: css-position, persistent, facebook-chat

i developed a radio stations widget (see it at my site). the problem is, i dont know how to make it persistent same like on the http://josephbeeson.com/gwapdemo/gwap.html . it's like facebook chatbar which not reload when navigate to any page. i have try n look for the demo codes but still not understand. please give step by step tutorial. i want to implement it on my social website http://www.heypy.com.

Answer (score 1):

The whole page does **not** get reloaded, the new content is just loaded via AJAX and displayed within the current document.

To make it *look* to the user like he’s navigated to some other URL, the address bar content is updated using the HTML5 History API.

> please give step by step tutorial.

Happy to give you the relevant keywords, so you can do research on them yourself. But won’t provide a private tutorial here, that’s not the purpose of this site. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: i mean give a demo of the empty demo page. then i can change it to my web app.

Comment: ok i tell the problem. I saw the demo page. But there are too many content and unwanted mp3 songs. It's makes me so confuse to get the basic code.

Comment: You got the keywords – AJAX, HTML5 History API – so now please go and do your own research and reading up on them.

Comment: Nope. This is not a tutorial section. Please learn how to gather information on technologies you want to use on the web.

Comment: so i assume that u just to teach after i pay right? How much u will charge? I will pay.

Comment: Nope, I’m not here to get paid. But advice, hints and keywords are all that I’ll give – I won’t do anyone’s work _for_ them. There’s lots of tutorials out there on AJAX and how to (re)load only parts of a page with, and information on the mentioned API is not hard to find either.

Comment: as i mentioned before.. i just need simple code. there's many demos out there... but it crowded with unwanted content...so confuse. how u understand my problem...i need more hints..the core basic code..please

Comment: hello all web developers here....why u all so selfish? please give a basic code..

Comment: i found the video tutorial..there are two videos:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQFokucBXVA and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytKc0QsVRY4&feature=plcp . but i need to choose a simple and easy one. which one should i prefer?